# How to pass parameters with quotes via ssh

Tags: ssh, cmd, quotes

When I run a script in my Linux server as follow:

```
./myscript \"hello\"
```

The script then receives the parameter as **"hello"**. Now, I want to be able to run this script remotely from a different host via ssh. If the ssh connection was Linux to Linux, the following works:

```
ssh remote-host ./myscript \\\"hello\\\"
```

However, if you ssh connection was Windows 10 to Linux. The above does not work, the remote script receives the parameter as **\hello"**--note the extra backslash and missing double quote. I have tried the following and none works:

```
ssh remote-host ./myscript \\\"hello\\\"
ssh remote-host ./myscript ^"hello^"
ssh remote-host ./myscript ""hello""
ssh remote-host ./myscript '"hello"'
```

The only workaround I can think of is to create another shell script which contains:

```
./myscript \"hello\"
```

Then scp this script to the remote Linux server and execute it there. So, is there a way for me to properly quote my arguments?

Comment: I have no Windows box to test, but does `ssh remote-host './myscript \"hello\"'` work? Knowing that `ssh` is just going to join its arguments to pass to `sh -c` on the remote host, I find it simpler to just pass a single string in the first place.

Comment: If `^` is the escape character, does one of `^\"hello^\"` or `'\"hello\"'` work?

Comment: The goal is to make sure the remote end runs something like `sh -c './myscript \"hello\"'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following convenient wrapper script `ssh.sh`

```
cat <<'EOF' > ssh.sh
#!/bin/bash

function escape() {
  for arg in "$@"; do
    printf "%q " "$arg"
  done
}

ssh $(escape "$@")
EOF

chmod +x ssh.sh
```

Then you can safely call ssh via the `ssh.sh`, without worrying about escaping.

e.g.,

```
./ssh.sh host sh -c 'ls /'
```

Compare to standard ssh,

```
ssh host sh -c 'ls /'
```

does not work, it need be converted to

```
ssh host sh -c \'ls /\'
```